# ES6 - Class Methods not defined when extending - babel issue

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am extending a class, and adding some properties and methods to it:

```
class Cmp extends ConsentString {
  constructor(result = null) {
    super(result);
    this.setCmpId(52);
  }
  loaded() {
    return this.cmpLoaded;
  }
}
```

I am then creating a function which returns a promise to create a new instance of the class:

```
export default function initCmp(loaderData) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const cmp = new Cmp();
    console.log('testing', cmp.loaded()); // undefined!
    if (!cmp) reject();
    console.log('CMP: ', cmp); // this logs as you would expect apart from there are non of the methods with which I extend.
    resolve(cmp);
  });
```

I am able to access methods and properties from the original class, and any properties from my extension but not any of the methods - they are all undefined.

I have tried many things such as bind(this) and adding the method names to the constructor, nothing seems to work.

I also feel this bug was introduced as part of the Babel Transform Runtime I added to be able to use async/await.

EDIT: ConsentString class is here https://github.com/InteractiveAdvertisingBureau/Consent-String-SDK-JS/blob/master/src/consent-string.js

UPDATE: I have tried to run the flow without extending the class but rather creating a new class, all works fine - so the issue must be with extending, but I am unsure what that is, this is still an issue.

UPDATE 2: When I remove two plugins from babel: `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime` & `transform-async-to-generator` all works fine.

Please help!

Comment: Please post a running example which reproduces the error so that we can help you, knowing what is in the ConsentString class is critical.

Comment: The ConsentString class is an external library, not sure what I can snip to help, I have added a link.

Comment: is `setCmpId` a sync or async function?  constructors can only run synchronous code.  Are you expecting setup that can't happen in a constructor?  (grasping at straws because we cant see the class you are extending from)

Comment: It is a sync function. I can log the new cmp class to console, all is present on it apart from the methods with which I have extended it.

Comment: Ah I see it now with the edit.  Nothing necessarily stands out at first glance.  Have you tried running this in a node env that naturally supports async/await to see if it is something in your babel config thats introducing this bug?  Also, since 8.11 is LTS, are you forced to run on a legacy version?  Babel might not necessarily be required?

Comment: This is client side code.

Comment: yes but it can be executed in a node env without babel - do you get a different result?  if so, its your config most likely.. or some incompatibility therein.   Either way i see your edit says you got through it, so thumbs up for that.  Best of luck.

Comment: I did not get through it! Quite the opposite, extending the class means no methods are defined on the new class. I will try and run it in node.

Comment: @JamesLeClair yes this is being made an issue by babel, when I remove `transform-async-to-generator` and `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime` plugins it runs fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173404/discussion-between-ydennis-and-james-leclair).

Answer (score 0):

I have (thanks to a chat with @JamesLeClair) included babel-polyfill instead of the runtime which has solved the issue.

This is not the perfect solution as I am working on a library but keeps things moving for now!